# How to use React client to receive a message from a Socket.io server?

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, socket.io

I'm using a server (Node.js and Socket.io) to send a message between clients (React). I can send a message from Client 1 to Client 2, but for the second client to be able to visualize the message on the screen it has to click a button.
What I'm trying to achieve is to for the Client 2 to be able to visualize the message sent by the Client 1 automatically, without clicking on any button, directly when the Client 1 sends the message to the server and the server emits it.
Something like having a listener that is working permanently looking for each time that the servers send a "socket.emit("send_message", message)". The problem is that on the React client, my function "socket.on("send_message",...)" inside a useEffect that only works when I click the button.

Any help or references would be awesome, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if this the right approach but it worked for me.

Assuming the socket has been setup to connect to some url,

```
let [socket, setSocket] = useState(null)
useEffect(() => setSocket(io(socket_connect_url), [])
```

Then you could setup a hook to detect the event 'someEvent' like so,

```
  useEffect(() => {
    if(!socket) return;
    socket.on('someEvent', (recv) =>{
        try{
            // Process recv message here
            console.log(recv);
        }catch(err){
            console.log(err)
        }
    }, [socket])
  })
```